# Norm, Euclidean Space and Distance

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, soft-question, vector-spaces

To a complete layman, how would you define the following terms intuitively?

$norm$ ,
$euclidean$ $space$ ,
and $euclidean$ $distance$ ?

Note: I have tagged Linear Algebra and Probability Theory because I am trying to read about stochastic convergence which has Euclidean distance mentioned in the source.

Comment: Quite unrelated to (probability).

Answer (score 0):

*Norm* (I'm assuming *Euclidean*): length, as you're used to measuring it with a measuring tape.

*Euclidean space*: a space in which you measure the length in such a way, although it may have more dimensions than you're used to.

*Euclidean distance*: length of the (shortest) line between the objects in question.